# issue with c# xml documentation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following comment.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// MSDN Time Format compatible with <see cref="DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)"/> 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>MSDN Time Format compatible with <see cref="DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)"/></returns>
```

but I'm not sure why I receive the following warning

> Warning   7   **XML comment on 'MSLab.DateTime.SystemTimeProvider.GetTimeFormat()' has cref attribute 'DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)' that could not be resolved** F:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSLab\trunk\MSLab\MSLab\DateTime\SystemTimeProvider.cs  110 57  MSLab

Comment: I copied your code and couldn't reproduce the error.  Do you have a `using System;`?

Comment: Michael Liu caught it as it was very subtle (but right in my face).  I have an MSLab.DateTime namespace which was conflicting.  It's too bad the warning message did not say "ambiguous" like it does when compiling code in such a manor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the warning message, it looks like your `SystemTimeProvider` class is inside a namespace named `DateTime`, which has the same name as the .NET `DateTime` type. To resolve this conflict, change your `cref` to `"System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)"`:

```
/// <summary>
/// MSDN Time Format compatible with <see cref="System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)"/>
/// </summary>
/// <returns>MSDN Time Format compatible with <see cref="System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)"/></returns>
```

Comment: Wow I banged my head for a while and I never even noticed.  That namespace needs to be renamed me thinks.  Either way providing the fully qualified name did the trick.  Thanks!